# CloudWatch log groups which are not in use

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is there a way to list all the AWS CloudWatch log groups which are not in use?

Comment: There is no concept of "in-use". Apps simply send information to CloudWatch Logs and it stores that data. You could make assumptions about "in-use" depending upon how recently data was received.

Comment: I have taken note of it....Thank you for spending time on this.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tool like [aws-cloudwatch-log-clean](https://github.com/four43/aws-cloudwatch-log-clean) would be the easiest way if you have a lot of log groups to clean up.

Comment: thanks for the reply.....for cleaning logs we can follow this script but am looking for the list of log groups which are not in use. Once list is prepared based on that need to work on deletion part.

Comment: It has a dry-run option that outputs the list without making changes. There are other similar scripts in Github as well using different approaches. You might be able to find something there.